# Multiply a row corresponding to the condition in r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe which consists of three columns. Country, Currency and Salary. 
[the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwzVE.jpg)

My concern here is that I want all the salary for a particular country to be in single currency. For example, I want Brazil's salary to be in BSD. So wherever the currency is different that is here it is INR I want to multiply it with the conversion rate of something say 6.789. Likewise I want to do for other countries as well. I have written a piece of code using if statements. But I am not getting the Salary column multiplied by the conversion rates.

```
if (df$Country == "Brazil"){
  if(df$Currency == "INR"){
    df$Salary <- df$Salary*2.50
  }
}else if(df$Country == "India"){
  if(df$Currency == "USD"){
    df$Salary <- df$Salary*6.789
  }else if (df$Currency == "CHF"){
    df$Salary <-df$Salary*5.67
  }
}else {
  df$Salary <- df$Salary*1
}
```

I still get the same salary as the initial one. Is there any other way to sort it out?

Comment: You'd arguably be better off by creating a lookup dataframe table with all of your conversion rates stored within it and then joining that to your dataframe using merge. This would also also allow you to store multiple conversion rates without ending up with a monstrous collection of nested if statements.

Answer (score 2):

Likely if this is a something you need to do regularly there are better options for automation, including a lookup table that Tumbledown mentioned.

If other methods are not possible and you still need to run some conditional statements, You could utilize tidyverse for perhaps a cleaner and easier to read solution with mutate and case_when.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
        mutate(Salary = case_when(Country == "Brazil" & Curency == "INR" ~ Salary * 2.5,
                          Country == "India" & Currency == "USD" ~ Salary * 6.789,
                          Country == "India" & Currency == "CHF" ~ Salary * 5.67,
                          TRUE ~ Salary))
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar idea with base R:

```
country <- c(rep("Brazil", 7), rep("India", 7))
currency <- c(rep("BSD", 4), rep("INR", 5), rep("USD", 3), rep("CHF", 2))
salary <- c(70000, 45000, 13425, 67746, 87852, 18902, 56148,
  81871, 98767, 23456, 45688, 98287, 62290, 23623)
dd <- data.frame(country, currency, salary)
```

```
conversion <- NULL
conversion$INR2BSD <- 6.789
conversion$INR2CHF <- 4.5
conversion$USD2CHF <- 5
conversion <- data.frame(conversion)
```

```
dd$convrate <- 1
dd$convrate[dd$country == "Brazil" & dd$currency == "INR"] <- conversion$INR2BSD
dd$convrate[dd$country == "India" & dd$currency == "INR"] <- conversion$INR2CHF
dd$convrate[dd$country == "India" & dd$currency == "USD"] <- conversion$USD2CHF

dd$conv_salary <- dd$salary * dd$convrate
```